# Apply tier price to cart for configurable products

Tags: magento-2.1

does anyone know a way or extension for Magento2 that would achieve the following for configurable products and tier prices when added to the cart...

Tshirt sold in Blue, Green, Red

100 Tshirts = £1.50

200 Tshirts = £1.00

300 Tshirts = £0.50

Separately add 100 Blue Tshirts, 100 Green Tshirts, 100 Red Tshirts to the cart

Unit price of each item in the cart should be £0.50 (to reflect tier price) and not £1.50

Cart price rules and manual discounts are not feasible as there are too many tier prices and hundreds of products that this applies to.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Similar to this extension but for Magento 2.1 github.com/customgento/CustomGento_ConfigurableTierPrices

Comment: We currently develop our extension for 2.2. It will be a paid extension though. I will post an answer here as soon as we are live.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly named our free extension [tier price for configurable products (M1)](https://github.com/customgento/CustomGento_ConfigurableTierPrices). We finally managed to develop the same extension for Magento 2. As written in the comments, [tier price for configurable products (M2)](https://marketplace.magento.com/customgento-module-configurable-tier-prices-m2.html) is a paid extension though. The M2 version basically works like the M1 version, but has some extra features:

- tier price calculation across multiple variations
- updated calculation can be disabled for each configurable product
- updated calculation can be disabled for each category
- [new] tier price calculation type can be configured:

  - use the highest tier price
  - use the lowest tier price
  - use the tier price of the respective product

You can find some screenshots on our [docs page](http://docs.customgento.com/tier-prices-for-configurable-products-m2.html).

Mind that the extension only works for Magento >= 2.2 since some serious configurable product bugs have been fixed in this version. But if you still use Magento 2.1, you should upgrade anyway :-)